# Table relations for more than two tables

Tags: django, django-models

I have the next model:

```
class SerialNumber(models.Model):
    prefix = models.CharField(max_length=8)

class Position(models.Model):
    serial_number = models.ForeignKey(SerialNumber)

class Car(models.Model):
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position)

class Owner(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

How can I get all owners who has special prefix and reverse situation (get all serial numbers for owner)?

I tried something like:

```
Owner.objects.select_related('car__position__serial_number').filter(prefix='ZXC')

Owner.objects.select_related('car__position__serial_number').filter(name='Joe')
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Owner.objects.filter(car__position__serial_number__prefix = 'ZXC')
```